# How do I create a transparent gif in Go?

Tags: go, gif

when I encode a gif in Go, the background is all black. How do I make the background transparent?

Here is some code in my http handler. (w is the responseWriter)

```
m := image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, pixelWidth, pixelHeight))
gif.Encode(w, m, &gif.Options{NumColors: 16})
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I read the source of image/gif and found that there just has to be a transparent color on your palette.

```
var palette color.Palette = color.Palette{
    image.Transparent,
    image.Black,
    image.White,
    color.RGBA{0, 255, 0, 255},
    color.RGBA{0, 100, 0, 255},
}

m := image.NewPaletted(image.Rect(0, 0, pixelWidth, pixelHeight), palette)
gif.Encode(w, m, &gif.Options{})
```

Comment: Note this can be done either by using your own `*image.Paletted` as the image to encode (as shown), or by setting [`gif.Options`'s](https://golang.org/pkg/image/gif/#Options) `Quantizer` field to a [`draw.Quantizer`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/draw/#Quantizer) that puts a transparent color into the palette (perhaps when detecting any transparency in the image). The default when the `Quantizer` field is nil is to use a static palette with no transparency.